# html5 & javascriptmvc ie problem

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, model-view-controller, html

Why do I get errors in ie6 when developing an html5 app with javascriptmvc?

The problem appears when I include in the header:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="js/libs/modernizr-1.6.min.js"></script>
```

And then before closing body:

```
<script type='text/javascript'
    src='../steal/steal.js?appname,development'>
</script>
```

When I remove the html5shiv the app works but then it's impossible to style html5 elements.

Comment: I deleted the html5shiv becouse it's in Modernizr. No errors anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need the html5shiv if you're using Modernizr, as Modernizr includes the same functionality itself.

Quote from the Modernizr homepage:

> Lastly, Modernizr also adds support for styling and printing HTML5 elements. This allows you to use more semantic, forward-looking elements such as `<section>`, `<header>` and `<dialog>` without having to worry about them not working in Internet Explorer.